# What is a good method to determine a memory leak in node.js?

Tags: memory, node.js, profiler

When deployed my node.js application hits memory related errors (i.e. FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory).  I would like to profile my node locally to see what is eating up memory but am not sure where to start.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918557/debugging-memory-leaks-with-node-js-server

Comment: The answer there (use profiler from node inspector) has us use something labeled "VERY EXPERIMENTAL" and not recommended by the author himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) and the [v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler) to do this. Install it from npm:

```
$ npm install v8-profiler
```

And then use it to take heap snapshots (taken from instructions):

```
var profiler = require('v8-profiler');
var snapshot = profiler.takeSnapshot([name])      //takes a heap snapshot
```

Comment: v8-profiler is currently broken for me: https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/9

Comment: But when it works again this will probably be the best way, thanks!